# Understanding how to Plot Signals in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

So I am trying to plot basic signals in MATLAB for an assignment, and I am wondering how to do so. I have done the other assignments by doing them on paper and finding the specific points at where the signal changes, then plotting it that way. For example`

```
x1=[-4 -4 -1]
y1=[0 -.5 0]
x2=[1 4 4]
y2=[0 .5 0]
plot(x1,y1)
hold on
plot(x2,y2)
hold off
xlim([-5 5])
ylim([-5 5])`
```

I'm wondering if this is the most optimal way to plot these symbols, or are there better options.
An example for the signal equations I am talking about is "plot x1(t)=u(t+1)-u(t-5) where -7<t<7seconds.

Comment: Give more detail on `u(t)`. Also for **signal**, the preferred data visualization function is `stem` not `plot`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.